# Асинхронная запись в файл WinApi

Tags: c++, c, winapi, асинхронность

Есть программа поиска всех файлов каталоге С.

Нужно по каждому найденному файлу сделать запись в текстовый файл в асинхронном режиме.

Проблема в том что в файл записывается только 1 строчка а дальше в GetLastError-ошибка хендла, при поиске в других каталогах вообще никаких результатов.

Вот код программы.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE   102400
#define REPEAT_COUNT 1
#define SECTOR_SIZE  512

void recursive_find_files (char *path)
{

        void *buff=NULL;
OVERLAPPED io;
 HANDLE event = CreateEventA(0, false, false, 0);
 buff = VirtualAlloc(NULL, CHUNK_SIZE, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE); //резервируем память
FillMemory(buff, '0', CHUNK_SIZE);
DWORD ff;
int i;
    char temp [MAX_PATH] = {'\0'};
    wsprintf (temp, "%s\\*.*", path);
     HANDLE file = CreateFile("file.txt",GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);

    ZeroMemory(&io, sizeof(io)); //инциализация структуры
 SetFilePointer(file, REPEAT_COUNT * CHUNK_SIZE, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    SetEndOfFile(file);
     WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile (temp, &fd); 
    //WriteFile(file,buff14, sizeof(buff14), &ff, NULL );
    if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
         do
         {
              if (strcmp (".", fd.cFileName) != 0 && strcmp ("..", fd.cFileName) != 0)
              {
                   if (fd.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                   {
                        printf ("dir \t%s\\%s\n", path, fd.cFileName);

                        char res [MAX_PATH] = {'\0'};
                        sprintf_s (res, "%s\\%s", path, fd.cFileName);

                        recursive_find_files (res);
                   }
                   else 
                       {
                           printf ("file \t%s\\%s\n", path, fd.cFileName);
                           WriteFile(file, fd.cFileName, strlen(fd.cFileName), &ff, &io);

                     printf("WriteFile failed. GetLastError: %d\n", GetLastError());


                   }

              }
         }
         while (FindNextFile (handle, &fd));
    }
    FindClose (handle);
     CloseHandle(file);
}

int main ()
{
    recursive_find_files ("C:\\");
    getchar ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для начала - у вас уже имеется этот файл? А то ведь у вас флаг OPEN_EXISTING

Comment: Да, файл имеется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы открываете файл `"file.txt"` для записи в монопольном режиме затем в рекурсивных вызовах `recursive_find_files` пытаетесь открыть его снова, и все эти последующие попытки оканчиваются неудачей. Откройте файл один раз вне этой рекурсивной функции и передавайте в нее уже открытый файловый дескриптор. В плане асинхронности тут тоже не все гладко, так как результат асинхронной операции нигде не проверяется и вообще нет ожидания ее окончания (буфер с записываемыми данными должен оставаться валиден до окончания операции).

Кроме того, следует проверять результаты большинства вызываемых функций (в т.ч. `VirtualAlloc` `CreateEventA`) и использовать Unicode варианты этих функций и `wchar_t` строки (т.е. `CreateEventW` `CreateFileW`).

Comment: Перенесла  CreateFile в main и передаю файловый дескриптор. Поставила точку остановы около WriteFile и при завершении программы в файл записывается только имя файла на котором программа остановилась. т.е. данные каждый раз перезаписываются. а если не ставить точку остановы то там каждый раз разный набор букв всегда определенной длины. Не могу понять от чего это зависит

Comment: @АлинаСтроителева Так я же написал по этому поводу в ответе. Следует проверять результат записи, дожидаться окончания записи и принимать меры к тому, чтобы буфер с записываемыми данными оставался валиден до окончания записи. Сейчас содержимое `cFileName` может перезаписываться или вообще становиться невалидным по окончании каждой итерации в то время как эти данные еще не были записаны.

Comment: Можете ли Вы примерно написать как это должно выглядеть? Я еще плохо в этом разбираюсь.

Comment: @АлинаСтроителева Следует отслеживать все записи. Держать список структур с полями `OVERLAPPED` и `wstring`. При каждой записи добавлять в список такую структуру, копировать в строку `cFileName`. Затем проверять результаты прежних операций вызывая `GetOverlappedResult` и избавляться от завершившихся. Как-то так.